# Getting timeout error in AWS Glue job while trying to ingest data into DynamoDB table

Tags: timeout

I have created a job in AWS glue that will pull the data based on incremental timestamp and it will ingest that data into a dynamodb table. Getting the following error and in dynamodb not able to see the records "Error while updating latest pull date into the table: %s Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazon.com/"

I have tried to change the Job Timeout from "Job Details" tab of the glue job but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.